# Curved text in latex table column problem

Tags: tables, xetex, text

I have one problem with my table. Why fourth column of my table has curved text?

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]%
\caption{XMM-Newton expositions for Gaia18awg\label{tab5}}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{500pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccD{.}{.}{3}c@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
Exp.ID & Instrument & Mode & Filter & Duration \\
\midrule
S001& EMOS1 & Small Window & MEDIUM   & 16626s\\
S002& EMOS2 & Large Window  &MEDIUM & 16604s\\
S003& EPN & Small Window   & MEDIUM & 16139s \\
S006& OM & Image & V   &4000s\\
S007& OM & Image   &U & 3999s\\
S008& OM & Image   & UVW1 & 4001s\\
S009& OM & Image & UVW1  & 3400s\\
S004& RGS1 & Spectroscopy HER+SES &N/A& 16911s\\
S005& RGS2 & Spectroscopy HER+SES & N/A & 16909s\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `D{.}{.}{3}` with `r` (for upright right aligned text) or `l` (for upright left aligned text) or `c` (for upright centered text)

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue, but you might want to use a more "descriptive" key for your `\label` command. Table number might change and a key containing a number might confuse you later, especially if the table with the label "tab5" ands up with a different number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `D` type column (from the `dcolumn` package) is intended to be used for columns containing numbers. Since your column only contains text, a `r`, `l`or `c` column (depending on the desired horizontal alignment) would be better suited.

Depending on the size of the page and the margins, the table might be wider than the textwidth. To prevent this, you might want to consider using `\textwidth` instead of `500pt`.

Personally, I would not recommend stretching a table to be significantly wider than it yould naturally be since the additional white space does not improve the readability. I also recommend placing repeated information into the column header (seconds in the last column). In the following MWE, I have thus added a second example table, in which I also used an `S` type column from `siunitx` to improve the alignment of the numbers in the last column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]%
\caption{XMM-Newton expositions for Gaia18awg\label{tab5}}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lccrc@{}}
\toprule
Exp.ID & Instrument & Mode & Filter & Duration \\
\midrule
S001& EMOS1 & Small Window & MEDIUM   & 16626s\\
S002& EMOS2 & Large Window  &MEDIUM & 16604s\\
S003& EPN & Small Window   & MEDIUM & 16139s \\
S006& OM & Image & V   &4000s\\
S007& OM & Image   &U & 3999s\\
S008& OM & Image   & UVW1 & 4001s\\
S009& OM & Image & UVW1  & 3400s\\
S004& RGS1 & Spectroscopy HER+SES &N/A& 16911s\\
S005& RGS2 & Spectroscopy HER+SES & N/A & 16909s\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!htbp]%
\caption{XMM-Newton expositions for Gaia18awg\label{tab5}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llllS[table-format=5]}
\toprule
Exp.ID & Instrument & Mode & Filter & {Duration (\si{\second})} \\
\midrule
S001& EMOS1 & Small Window & MEDIUM   & 16626\\
S002& EMOS2 & Large Window  &MEDIUM & 16604\\
S003& EPN & Small Window   & MEDIUM & 16139 \\
S006& OM & Image & V   &4000\\
S007& OM & Image   &U & 3999\\
S008& OM & Image   & UVW1 & 4001\\
S009& OM & Image & UVW1  & 3400\\
S004& RGS1 & Spectroscopy HER+SES &N/A& 16911\\
S005& RGS2 & Spectroscopy HER+SES & N/A & 16909\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```